# How can I get google to quickly show new pages on my site?

Tags: seo

For example, if you asked a question on yahoo answers, it'd get shown in google results within minutes. For my site, it takes days.

Comment: Not the right place for this question. Ask on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks Oded, didn't know about that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help a little bit:

1) go to http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ and insert you website and download an xml map, then upload it in you website folder. You can also make it by your own (google it)

2) go to http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ and add your website (if it is not present yet)

3) click on you site and in the bottom right you can see the sitemaps tab, you can enter the url of your updated xml map

4) in your robots.txt file add this:
User-agent: * 
Sitemap: http://www.yoursite.com/sitemap.xml

5) go to facebook, twitter, delicious, digg, and other social bookmarking and save your new pages

Answer (score 1):

You can't control that. The Google crawler follows links to find new pages, thus new content on yahoo is probably updated quite instantly. As for your page, you just need to make it as easy as possible on the crawler. Set good meta tags and place links to your page in forums and other pages.

Codemonkey

Answer (score 1):

Google tend to visit more frequently sites that change frequently. Which makes sense.

For exemple news websites are visited multiple times a day, white static website are visited few times a month.

Answer (score 1):

Take a in this way.

In order to make your new page show up on Google, you need to let its crawler find / index your new page.

At this point you get two options:

1. Proactively put your new page to it.  you can

a. submit URL of your new page to Google(Personally I do not think it is so useful).

b. Put your link on third party sites(usually called link building and ideally the more inbound links you get, the higher you pr is), especially those that enjoy high PR or freed fresh content to Google and their visitors.

c. Site map（unless your site is dynamic, this methods is also not so good, personal experience）.

2. Highly recommended. Build fresh content, Google crawler loves fresh content. The more you feed it with fresh content, the frequently it will visit your site.